# Weird effects in .css files after activating compression

Tags: c#, asp.net, compression

Yesterday I activated compression on my website, like this:

```
void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    string encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");

    if (encodings == null)
        return;

    string url = app.Request.RawUrl.ToLower();           


    if (url.Contains(".js") || url.Contains(".aspx") || url.Contains(".css") || url.Contains("ajax.ashx"))
    {

        Stream baseStream = app.Response.Filter;
        encodings = encodings.ToLower();

        if (encodings.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
        else if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
        }
    }
}
```

Last night, people were complaining about the styles for the website being broken. I tried the site in Firefox and Chrome and got the same problem until I did a forced refresh, clearing the cache.

This morning, I opened Safari to see what it looked like in that browser, and checked the stored style sheets. Here is a section of the top line:

```
���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"�~+M�m�?��{�7y����l]�餮���N���̛�x�Ϋ�Q�cMVg��
```

I think either Safari has tried to uncompress something that was not compressed to begin with, or else it has recieved a compressed file and not decoded it.

Is this a one-time problem, that will be cleared up as soon as visitors to my site clear their cache, or have I made a mistake in writing my HttpCompression function?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just let [IIS do this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322603) for you?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment The guy who was developing the site before me did it like this (He only had compression enabled for responses to ajax.ashx). It seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my problem here was related to my lack of a `Vary:Accept-Encoding` header being added to my responses. Please see [this related question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848796/what-does-varyaccept-encoding-mean). My code now looks like this:

```
if (url.Contains(".js") || url.Contains(".aspx") || url.Contains(".css") || url.Contains("ajax.ashx"))
{
    app.Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");

    encodings = encodings.ToLower();

    if (encodings.Contains("gzip") || encodings == "*")
    {
        app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

    }
    else if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
    {
        app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead :

```
   HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        string acceptEncoding = app.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        Stream prevUncompressedStream = app.Response.Filter;

        if (!(app.Context.CurrentHandler is Page ||
            app.Context.CurrentHandler.GetType().Name == "SyncSessionlessHandler") ||
            app.Request["HTTP_X_MICROSOFTAJAX"] != null)
            return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
            return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToLower();


        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip") || acceptEncoding == "*")
        {
            // gzip
            app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(prevUncompressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            // defalte
            app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(prevUncompressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What does the `if (!app.Context.CurrentHandler is Page || .....` statement check for, exactly? I'm cautious about compressing things that it doesn't make sense to compress, like images. For instance, I serve some dynamic PNGs from a `userImage.ashx` file.