# Unable to append 'Vary' header to response

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

I'm trying to add a `Vary: Accept-Encoding` header to the response to files that I compress, [as advised earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848796/what-does-varyaccept-encoding-mean).

However, for some reason this is not possible - either from the Visual Studio test server, or an IIS server.

I have the following code:

```
if (url.Contains(".js") || url.Contains(".aspx") || url.Contains(".css"))
{
    app.Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
    app.Response.AppendHeader("Varye", "Accept-Encoding"); // for testing
    app.Response.AppendHeader("Varye", "Accept-Things");   // for testing
    app.Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Stuff");     // for testing
    app.Response.AppendHeader("Var", "Accept-Items");      // for testing

    encodings = encodings.ToLower();

    if (encodings.Contains("gzip") || encodings == "*")
    {
        app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

    }
}
```

this results in the following response header:

```
Status=OK - 200
Server=ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date=Fri, 21 Oct 2011 12:24:11 GMT
X-AspNet-Version=4.0.30319
Varye=Accept-Encoding, Accept-Things
Var=Accept-Items
Content-Encoding=gzip
Cache-Control=public
Etag="1CC8F2E9D772300"
Content-Type=text/css
Content-Length=16200
Connection=Close
```

As you can see, the `Vary` header is not present. Meaningless headers with similar syntax are present, so there must be something, somewhere, taking out the Vary header before it is sent.

I don't know if it is relevant, but here is where I define my compression module in web.config:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="CompressionModule" type="Utility.HttpCompressionModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

(Where Utility.HttpCompressionModule is the class which the code excerpt I provided above belongs to.)

Why is it that I can't add the `Vary` header?

**EDIT:** Eric C's solution has left me with code like this:

```
if (url.Contains(".js") || url.Contains(".aspx") || url.Contains(".css"))
{
    app.Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("Accept-Encoding");

    encodings = encodings.ToLower();

    if (encodings.Contains("gzip") || encodings == "*")
    {
        app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

    }
```

But, the headers look like this:

```
Status=OK - 200
Server=ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date=Mon, 24 Oct 2011 09:26:37 GMT
Content-Encoding=gzip
Cache-Control=public
Etag="1CC7A09FDE77300"
Vary=*
Content-Type=application/x-javascript
Content-Length=44447
Connection=Close
```

(No idea why this is `application/x-javascript` as its set in the HTML as `text/javascript`, but this is irrelevant.)

As you can see, I now have a vary header, but it is set as `Vary=*` rather than `Vary=Accept-Encoding`, as you would expect from my code in the compression module.

What is going on here? How do I get the `Vary` header set correctly?

**Second Edit:**
I'm going to paste the source code for the whole class. There isn't much more to it than I have already posted, but it might help to give a grasp of exactly what I'm doing:

```
public class HttpCompressionModule : IHttpModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AjaxHttpCompressionModule"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public HttpCompressionModule()
    {
    }

    #region IHttpModule Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes of the resources (other than memory) used by the module that implements <see cref="T:System.Web.IHttpModule"/>.
    /// </summary>
    void IHttpModule.Dispose()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a module and prepares it to handle requests.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">An <see cref="T:System.Web.HttpApplication"/> that provides access to the methods, properties, and events common to all application objects within an ASP.NET application</param>
    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.context_BeginRequest));
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the BeginRequest event of the context control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        string encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");
        Stream baseStream = app.Response.Filter;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodings))
            return;


        string url = app.Request.RawUrl.ToLower();

        if (url.Contains(".js") || url.Contains(".css") || url.Contains("ajax.ashx"))
        {
            app.Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("Accept-Encoding");

            encodings = encodings.ToLower();

            if (encodings.Contains("gzip") || encodings == "*")
            {
                app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
                app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

            }
            else if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
                app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Further, here is the System.Web section of my web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <!--<compilation debug="true"></compilation>-->
    <trace enabled="true" traceMode="SortByTime"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
    <!-- custom errors-->
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
    <!-- Membership -->
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SQLServerAuth" applicationName="mycompany" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1024"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <!-- Roles -->
    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add connectionStringName="SQLServerAuth" applicationName="mycompany" name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!-- Authentication -->
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="false"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".AUTH" protection="All" timeout="2" path="/">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="CompressionModule" type="Utility.HttpCompressionModule"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

There isn't much more to say. There is no other non-standard stuff that we are doing with the site, that I know about. Any ideas?

Comment: I test it via `Response.AppendHeader` and `Response.AddHeader` and both are working! Can you explain more your source-code?

Comment: I test it again and works! by `Append` and `Add` both! You limit the module to some extensions only: `if (url.Contains(".js") || url.Contains(".css") || url.Contains("ajax.ashx"))` do you test with this extension's header? add a `.aspx` extension in `if` and test. There is not any issue in code and it works correctly.

Comment: It's really strange that this isn't working for me. However, with the debugger I've confirmed that the `Content-Encoding` logic is being seen for the files I want to compress, at the moment my `.aspx` files are all set to `No-Cache` or `Private`, and I'm mostly interested in seeing that my static content files, which are quite large, are cached correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, this is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758474/iis-gzip-compression-filter-removes-pre-existing-vary-header) with the IIS compression module overwriting the `Vary` header specifically and has been addressed by [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2877816).

If you can't ensure the hotfix is installed then another workaround is to append the header using [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in your Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Append 'Vary: X-Requested-With' header" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_VARY" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}, X-Requested-With" replace="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Set 'Vary: X-Requested-With' header if no others" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_VARY" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="X-Requested-With" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10):

As of IIS 7.5, the Vary header is overwritten by the gzip IIS filter (gzip.dll), that implements the DyanamicCompressionModule. The filter always sets the header to "Vary: Accept-Encoding", regardless of changes made in ASP.NET code. As of today, the only workaround is to disable compression for dynamic content and then implement it in code. Here's how:

1. Remove the following line from Web.config:

   `<add name="CompressionModule" type="Utility.HttpCompressionModule"/>`
2. Then go to IIS management console and make sure compression is not enabled for dynamic content.
3. Implement compression manually in `Global.asax.cs`, method `HttpApplication.Application_BeginRequest`:

```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
       context.Response.Filter 
          = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
       context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
       context.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;

       // We can now set additional Vary headers...
       context.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders.UserAgent = true;
       context.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["X-Requested-With"] = true;
   }
```

This is an issue that was recently [reported to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758474/iis-gzip-compression-filter-removes-pre-existing-vary-header).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've recently come back to this project too, so it's great timing. I'll try to remember where I was and try out your solution on monday.

Comment: Replacing AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding"); by Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true; gave me desired result. The earlier way, if once the uncompressed page got cached, then requesting compressed would give the uncompressed cached page only.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("Accept-Encoding");
Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
```

Since it seems in the above that something has convinced the code that * is appropriate here, and you're certain it isn't.

Note that with IE there's a flaw in the caching mechanism (partially fixed, IIRC with IE9 but not before) where it takes such a vary header to indicate total inability to cache (this is valid, but sub-optimal behaviour). For this reason, some people prefer to vary by User-Agent because while Accept-Encoding is the technically correct value to send:

1. IE will cache this correctly.
2. A User-Agent that varies in what Accept-Encoding header it sends is possible, but unlikely in what will be encountered in the field.

**Note:** You must also make sure that you send different E-Tags with the different versions (g-zipped, deflated and uncompressed) as E-Tags label entities (the bunch of bytes sent, including any Content-Encoding but not including any Transport-Encoding) rather than resources, and not varying the E-Tag can result in much the same sort of SNAFU that you are setting `Vary: Accept-Encoding` to avoid.

If you can't make it vary the E-Tag, then you'd be better off omitting it and using last-modified alone for conditional GETs.

---

Incidentally, the answer to your wondering about why application/x-javascript is set, is that that is the content-type the server is associating with ".js". The hint in the HTML won't affect that as it isn't something the server sees for this request, though it **could** be used to over-ride the content-type if something bogus like text/plain was sent by the server (the standards are unclear and user-agent behaviour could vary while remaining within the letter of the standard). Since browsers generally all consider application/javascript application/x-javascript and text/javascript to mean javascript, it matters little here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll use `User-Agent` if I manage to get this working. I tried `SetOmitVaryStar(true)`, and this resulted in there being no `Vary` header present in the response. If I don't use the `SetOmitVaryStar()` method, the `Vary` header has a value of `*`. However, if I don't use the `SetOmitVaryStar()` method and **also** don't use the `SetVaryByCustom()` method, the `Vary` header is not present. Which is really strange.

Comment: @Oliver How about if you do use SetOmitVaryStar and do use SetVaryByCustom?

Comment: That's what I tried first - the Vary field wasn't present in the response. I have no idea what kind of internal logic asp.net is working on to do this. It seems that the Vary header is by default not present, trying to use `SetVaryByCustom()` makes the header present but sets its value to `*`, but this can be supressed by using both `SetVaryByCustom()` and `SetOmitVaryStar()`, resulting in the header not being present again. I may turn off HttpCompression for now and set it aside as a project for another day...

Comment: @Oliver Two remaining ideas then. First, switch the order of SetVaryByCustom and SetOmitVaryStar. Second is just to not use the cache object model but to handle it all yourself - certainly I've found that to have other advantages in these cases (forcing the e-tag to be set differently for different compression types is easier for one thing), but it's hardly a simple change if you've been using it up until now :(

Comment: Heh, it also suddenly occurs to me, when looking into something else, that you could write a custom HttpEncoder that rewrote the Vary. That'd be pretty evil though.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I tried switching the order of those two function calls around, but it didn't help. It looks like I'm going to have to try something with HttpEncoders. I just wish I could work out why my site is behaving so weirdly - I'm not using any strange configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
app.Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("Accept-Encoding");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually add the header value to see `Vary: Accept-Encoding`.

```cs
response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
response.AddHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
```

Answer (score 1):

I also tried these

```
Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
Response.AddHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
```

, but wouldn't work.. This, however, did work:

```
Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
```

Comment: Finally! This is the only advice that worked. Typical struggle with M$ products... nothing works as expected. In PHP, the commands actually do what they are supposed to do.