# How to replace http header vary Accept-Encoding to vary User-agent in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing mobile, smartphone, desktop website with same URL dynamic content, i am unable to set vary user-agent. The default value is  Accept-Encoding is coming. How we can replace  vary:Accept-Encoding to vary:User-agent?

I tried all these

1.<%@ OutputCache Duration="180"  VaryByHeader="User-Agent" %>

2.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Vary", "User-Agent");

3.HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Vary", "User-Agent");

4.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("User-Agent");

5.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders.UserAgent = true;

6.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Vary", "User-Agent");

but still coming

Cache-Control:public, max-age=180
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:9741
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:19:23 GMT
Expires:Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:22:22 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:19:22 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
**Vary:Accept-Encoding**

where what i want is

Cache-Control:public, max-age=180
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:9741
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:19:23 GMT
Expires:Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:22:22 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:19:22 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
**Vary:User-Agent**

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to append 'Vary' header to response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849392/unable-to-append-vary-header-to-response)

Answer (score 0):

"If you want to cache only by HTTP header values, you must set the VaryByParam attribute to "None"."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a6s4ks5w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx