# Unable to set both GzipStream and Content-Encoding to gzip on the same response

Tags: c#, .net, gzip

I'm working on a CompressionModule to be used in web.config, I've broken up a bigger issue into this case which I'm stumped on.

For this example I've created a new MVC4 internet application and have made the following modifications to web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <!--
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  -->
  <add name="Content" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
</handlers>
<modules>
        <remove name="monorailRouting" />
      <add name="compressionModule" type="Platform.Web.CompressionModule" />
  <!--
  <add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      -->
</modules>
```

Where compression module is

```
namespace Platform.Web {
public class CompressionModule : IHttpModule {

    #region HTTP Header Constants
    private const string DEFLATE = "deflate";
    private const string GZIP = "gzip";
    private const string CONTENT_ENCODING = "Content-Encoding";
    private const string ACCEPT_ENCODING = "Accept-Encoding";
    private const string VARY = "Vary";
    #endregion

    #region IHttpModule Members
    public void Dispose() {
        //noop
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_CompressResponse);
    }


    void context_CompressResponse(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        string encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get(ACCEPT_ENCODING);

        if (encodings == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        encodings = encodings.ToLower();

        if (encodings.Contains(GZIP))
        {
            //1
            app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(app.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);

            //2
            app.Response.AppendHeader(CONTENT_ENCODING, GZIP);

        }

        app.Response.AppendHeader(VARY, CONTENT_ENCODING);



    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

And I am experiencing the following issues:

1. If line 1 and 2 exist the app loads fine. But nothing is apparently
   gzipped in the headers, nor the body. I'm determining this through Fiddler.
2. If line 1 exists but 2 doesn't the app loads but unreadable gzip is
       displayed in the browser.
3. If line 1 doesn't exists but 2 does the app fails to load but
       Content-Encoding: gzip is in the headers.

Anyone have some suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I believe should be done here are,

1. the response filter should be taken into a copy of stream
2. the vary by headers has to be changed

Try the following code:

```
void context_CompressResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

    string encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get(ACCEPT_ENCODING);
    if (encodings == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    encodings = encodings.ToLower();

    if (encodings.Contains(GZIP))
    {
        Stream baseStream = app.Response.Filter;

        //1
        app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(baseStream, CompressionMode.Compress);

        //2
        app.Response.AppendHeader(CONTENT_ENCODING, GZIP);
    }
    Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders[ACCEPT_ENCODING] = true;
}
```

Also, for further discussions, please look into this S[O article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849392/unable-to-append-vary-header-to-response)

Comment: No-go. I just get a uncompressed response similar to my first case.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Fiddler2 isn't reading the headers correctly.

If I view the response in Chrome I can see that Content-Encoding is being set to gzip.

-Geoff